# How to add a coloumn in crstal reports when some data added to a sql server table autamattically

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports

I want to add a column in to crystal report called summary get by end of month and I want to add a column into this report after run this report and after add data into SQL server table but it should be done by automatically for example table 1:

```
name age city
gayan 20  colombo
ruwan 35  kandy
kamal 65  galle
```

table 2:

```
name    loantype           loanamount
gayan  personal loan       3000
ruwan  housing loan        1000
```

so I created a report like this in crystal reports in vb.net project and using SQL pivot option

crystal report summary

```
name     age    personal loan     housing loan         
gayan    20       3000               0
ruwan    35        0                1000
```

after this system runs, I want to add a column automatically to this report when that table 2 add another row with another loan type
table 2

```
name loantype              loanamount
gayan  personal loan       3000
ruwan  housing loan        1000
kamal  property loan       5000
```

now report should be like this 
crystal report summary

```
name     age    personal loan     housing loan     property loan       
gayan    20       3000               0                  0
ruwan    35        0                1000                0
kamal    65        0                  0                5000
```

nut this should be done by automatically with how to do it?

Comment: Are you asking for the SQL way to do this?

Comment: you need to use cross tabs in crystal reports

Comment: better and easy way sql or crystal reports doesn't matter